# I want to Create Search API with Express & MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mern, rest

**I want to Create Search API using Express and MongoDB, I have created GET, POST, DELETE, UPDATE but I cant find anything about how do I Perform Search with same like GET POST or etc**

**I am Posting My Express API Code which already having GET POST DELETE, Now I just want to create Search like that please help me.**

```
const express = require('express')
const router = express.Router()
const cors = require('cors')

//Importing Jobs Model
const JobsModel = require('../../models/jobs')
const { find } = require('../../models/jobs')


//POST Req 
router.post('/', async (req,res) => {
    const newJobPost = new JobsModel(req.body)
    try{
        const jobPost = await newJobPost.save()
        if(!jobPost) throw Error('Error, JobPost Not Saved...!')

        res.status(200).json(jobPost)
    }catch(err){
        res.status(400).json({msg:err})
    }
})

//GET All Req 
router.get('/',cors(), async (req,res) => {
    try{
        const getJobs = await JobsModel.find()
        if(!getJobs) throw Error('Error, No Jobs Found...!')
        res.status(200).json(getJobs)
    }catch(err){
        res.status(400).json({msg:err})
    }
})

//GET Single Req 
router.get('/:id',cors(), async (req,res) => {
    try{
        const getJob = await JobsModel.findById(req.params.id)
        if(!getJob) throw Error('Error, Job Not Found...!')
        res.status(200).json(getJob)
    }catch(err){
        res.status(400).json({msg:err})
    }
})


//DELETE Req 
router.delete('/:id',cors(), async (req,res) => {
    try{
        const delJobs = await JobsModel.findByIdAndDelete(req.params.id)
        if(!delJobs) throw Error('No Jobs Found to Delete...!')
        res.status(200).json({success: true})
    }catch(err){
        res.status(400).json({msg:err})
    }
})


//UPDATE Req 
router.patch('/:id',cors(), async (req,res) => {
    try{
        const updateJob = await JobsModel.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id, req.body)
        if(!updateJob) throw Error('Error, No Jobs Found to Update...!')
        res.status(200).json({success: true})
    }catch(err){
        res.status(400).json({msg:err})
    }
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a query based GET route like below

```js
//GET Search 
router.get('search/', cors(), async (req, res) => {
    try{
        const searchParams = req.query
        console.log(searchParams)
        const jobs = await JobsModel.find(searchParams)
        if(!jobs) throw Error('Error, No Jobs Found...!')
        res.status(200).json(jobs)
    }catch(err){
        res.status(400).json({msg:err})
    }
})
```

now call this API with your parameters like below

`http://localhost/search?name=bob&age=25`

you'll get these parameters like this

```js
console.log(req.query);
{
   "name": "bob",
   "age" : "25"
}
```

If you have more and complex filters then create a POST route and send your params in `body` and use them inside mongoose `find`

Comment: **Bro its still not working, Returning 400 Status**

Comment: Calling API with this http://localhost:3040/jobs/search?title=post

Comment: put this route on the top of all routes